# Need Help with VNC and its code

Tags: android, screen-scraping, vnc, desktop-sharing

What I want to do is suppose open 10 windows of paint application on a Windows 7 computer. I would like to show these 10 different windows on 10 different touch enabled devices. I am planning to use androidVNCviewer on these devices which run android and use VNC server on the windows computer.

I want this VNC server to be able to share individual windows(application windows) to individual clients via different ports. So I would like to know if this is possible and if so then how should I proceed ( I can't seem to be able to make head and tail of the code and need help badly to understand the flow of the code ).
Any alternate solutions?

Devesh

p.s : I only want a way to share these 10 applications and not a webservice or something like that which allows collaborative work because I already have an application written(in .net) whose various instances need to be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do what you describe but probably not with any existing vnc servers. You will need to download libvnc, which is essentially a vnc server library. Using it, you provide a buffer to each instance of the library, and each client connects to a single instance.